# Prescribed me vs prescribed to me?

Tags: word-usage

> The medications that were **prescribed me** didn't work so well.
>
> The medications that were **prescribed to** me didn't work so well.
>
> My doctor **prescribed me** some medication.
>
> My doctor **prescribed** some medication **to** me.

Which one of those is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge the structure is:

> Prescribe **something** to **somebody.**
>
> Prescribe **someone something.**